# Character Returns In Yeoman Templates

Tags: yeoman, yeoman-generator

In my template files for my Yeoman generator I have if statements to decide whether or not to include some content in the generated files.  When the if condition is not satisfied I end up with character returns where the if statement was in the files produced from the template.  Is there any way to eliminate these?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is down to the placement of the if statements this is the way to use them for a list.

```
<ul>
    <li>HTML5 Boilerplate</li><% if (includeJeet) { %>
    <li>Jeet</li><% } %><% if (includeRespond) { %>
    <li>Respond</li><% } %>
</ul>
```

If the if statement commences on a new line then the new line is created.